# Display X images from a gallery in the sidebar

Tags: images, gallery, sidebar

I've been hunting around for a day for this answer and thought I should turn to StackExchange in the hopes someone has an aswer.

My goal is to display X images (for example, 4) in the sidebar of this one template, but I'd like it to be dynamic and either pull 4 random images, or the first or last 4 images in the gallery.

I'm currently using this code below to manually pull 4 images, but can someone provide code to be a bit more clever about it?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery include="317,309,325" columns="1" link="file"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a custom query in order to pull X amount of images. You could do the following (untested):

```
<?php

function custom_gallery_display( $number_of_images = 4 ) {

    //make sure you have access to the WPDB object
    global $wpdb;

    //pull 4 random attachments
    $images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $number_of_images");

    //may need to tweak this;
    //not sure what format the results are returned
    $image_ids = implode( ',', $images );

    //now print with random images
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery include="' . $image_ids . '" columns="1" link="file"]');

    return;

}

?>
```

That should do the trick, although it may need a bit of tweaking.

You should also check out the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

According to it, you can easily create the randomized order by setting the orderby attribute to RAND

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery include="317,309,325" columns="1" orderby="RAND" link="file"]'); ?>
```

However, if you are forced to use a custom query in order to use X amount of images, you may as well just randomize it at that point, as I did above in the query.

Comment: Btw, you could also use `get_posts( $args )` to accomplish the custom query. Probably more efficient.